# An inquiry about a h.264 derived stream protocol

Tags: aes, h.264

First off, please forgive my complete lack of knowledge in this field. I got some time ago a couple of really cheap wifi ip cameras that I was hoping to use on my local network. Unfortunately, it turned out the manufacturer (zmodo) had introduced about a year ago their own streaming protocol and had done away with the rtsp port present in previous models. The manufacturer supplied apps are only cloud based, which doesn't put me at ease. Luckily, people have been trying to come up with solutions to this and have been fairly successful with older models. So I tried to see what I can do myself.

In essence, the camera listens on port 8000 for 12 byte long commands. One of these commands triggers a stream of data. The data looks a little bit like a sequence of AVI chunks that start with either `00dc` or `01dc`. Just like in AVI, these tags are followed by a four-byte size (let's call it S) and 24 bytes that look like a time stamp (but could also contain more info). The total number of bytes between `00dc` or `01dc` tags is exactly 32 bytes more than S. So, we have something like this

```
30 30 64 63 S[0] S[1] S[2] S[3] ....24 bytes for a time stamp? ... S bytes of data that seems encrypted...

30 31 64 63 S[0] S[1] S[2] S[3] ....24 bytes for a time stamp? ... 00 00 00 01 61 .... S - 5 bytes of data...
```

The second type of chunk, prefixed by `01dc` seems to contain unencrypted B- or P-frame NAL units (if my basic understanding is correct), but my question is about the first type. The first type probably contains I-frames but I cannot find a NAL delimeter or type byte. Additionally, the first 32 bytes of the S bytes of actual data are the same for every unit, i.e. I have

```
30 30 64 63 S[0] S[1] S[2] S[3] ....24 bytes for a time stamp? ... 32 constant bytes ... S-32 bytes of data
```

The camera also provides a 128 bit key which I naturally assumed to be for stream encryption (although it could be for cloud authentication or TLS or who knows what). So my question is, in your experience, which (encrypted) version of h.264 is this closest to? Any idea what the 32 constant bytes are?

EDIT: I am not sure that the keyframes are encrypted, I am only speculating. Actually, they seem to contain large areas of constant bytes at the end (although the bytes change from one unit to the next, i.e. `e4  e4 .... e4` in one, then `93 93 .... 93`, which rules out AES I think)

Comment: This question is better suited for [reverseengineering.stackexchange.com](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I would record both the raw traffic from the cam and the "view" traffic from the cloud and try to correlate those. It's unlikely that the cloud server re-encodes the stream. Though it's highly likely that some built-in encryption key is used, so you won't be able to decrypt the raw traffic without reverse-engineering the camera firmware.